# How to get the document total count in a view quickly? (Lotus Domino)

Tags: ajax, lotus-domino, lotus

I want to get documents total count in a view by Ajax, like this: `h t t p://.../viewname?readviewentries` and I got an attribute called "toplevelentries", but there is a problem: The value was fixed whoever is logged on.

So, how can I get an exact value from there? that is, i need it only display documents count that the current user have allowed to access.

Answer (score 1):

Create an XPage "NumberOfViewEntries"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    rendered="false"
    viewState="nostate">
    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
        var response = externalContext.getResponse();

        response.setContentType('application/json');
        response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

        var vw:NotesView = session.getCurrentDatabase().getView(param.view);
        try {
            writer.write('{"entries":'  + vw.getAllEntries().getCount() + '}');
        } catch(e) {
            writer.write('{"error":"'  + e + '"}'); 
        }
        writer.endDocument();
    }]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
</xp:view>
```

and call URL

`http://server/database/NumberOfViewEntries.xsp?view=yourViewName`

It will return e.g.

```
{"entries":57}
```

It will count only those view entries the current user has at least reader access to.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! but i want to know that it would fast than Notesview.AllEntries.Count? The way that i'm using is call a URL http://server/database/GetViewCount?openagent and print result but it is so slow when there are a lot of documents in database.
i was wondering is there some function that i don't know can get exact value quickly?
Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think there is a faster solution than view.getAllEntries().getCount(). The view itself is precalculated and with view.getEntryCount() you get the number of entries very fast . But this is the number of *all* view entries. If you want to know the number of entries the current user can read Domino has to figure out which documents are readable for user and that takes time. The time for vw.getAllEntries().getCount() should be pretty much the same as it takes for selecting all documents in view with CTRL/A.

Comment: An XPage should still be slightly faster than invoking a ?OpenAgent url, but Knut is correct. The only way for any code to determine the number of documents accessible by a given user is to iterate through all the docs in the view. The API will do that for you down at a low level, but it still takes time. If you can create a categorize view on the Readers field, then it is possible that there are faster methods that you could take advantage of, but if Readers fields contain group or role names you'll have to code it to do all the work that the API already does for you implicitly.

Comment: God! our domino release is too low to use Xpage. Is there really no any solution can do that? i mean, something like "ReadViewEntries" URL command that Domino has provided?